# SQL Thesaurus searches

Tags: sql, sql-server, thesaurus

I have made a custom thesaurus file with entries as follows

```
<expansion>
  <sub>RGN</sub>
  <sub>Registered General Nurse</sub>
</expansion>
```

The problem I am having is when running the formsof(thesaurus, "RGN") search I am getting results that contain just Registered or General or Nurse, not the entire word set. Is there any way I can ensure SQL will only search for all three words together when I use thesaurus? I tried adding quotes in the thesaurus file, seemed to have no effect?

```
 <sub>"Registered General Nurse"</sub>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
<expansion>
  <sub>RGN</sub>
  <sub><![CDATA[Registered General Nurse]]></sub>
</expansion>
```

Comment: Same result, I am starting to suspect the problem may lie within the index itself and not the thesaurus, these anomaly's only seem to be occurring on certain records and searches. I will try rebuilding them today.